# Multiple file operations at the same time? Node.js

Tags: node.js, file, express, save

I am making a node.js web application. I want users to be able to submit something through a form and I am storing the data to a text file. What if multiple poeple submit something at the same time though? Will one person prevent another one from running the server side code? Or could there be issues with opening the file at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fs` module included with nodeJS includes both asynchronous, and synchronous operations. Using the synchronous operations would result in what you're worried about, the server would freeze up while someone is working with a file. This is why you should use the asynchronous options.

Because NodeJS runs in a single process, complex synchronous operations are dangerous to use when there is a large amount of activity. The asynchronous operations will free up the process while the file system does it's job in the background, allowing other requests to process until completed.

For example, if you were trying to write a file to the file system:

**synchronously**

```
fs.writeFileSync('groceries.txt', 'eggs, milk, bread');
// Stuck waiting until file is written
console.log('List Saved!');
console.log('continuing running');
```

The console would output:

```
List Saved!
continuing running
```

**Asynchronously**

```
fs.writeFile('groceries.txt', 'eggs, milk, bread', (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log('List saved!');
});

// Can continue running other things in the meantime
console.log('continuing running')
```

The console would output:

```
continuing running
List Saved!
```

Now if the writing is being done to the same file, you would definitely want to use `fs.createWriteStream` which would allow you to write repeatedly to the file. This is usually used by something like a logger, which needs to output to a file very rapidly, and will not cause conflicts if 2 things are being written at the same time.

Although it seems like a database would be an ideal choice for concurrent writing.

Comment: What if 2 people submit at the same time though? Even async file writing will lock the file for how long it takes to write. Will the second file operation wait until the first one is done or will it result in an error? Also thx for such a detailed answer :)

Comment: Are you writing to the same file, or different files?

Comment: I am writing to the same file

Comment: I added a small section to the bottom. I'm not an expert on how the filesystem handles writes, but I think there would be some complications if 2 users tried to write at the same time. Either one would get overridden or the user would have to wait. I think this might depend on how the OS handles files.

Comment: So I could use:
let writer = fs.createWriteStream('out.txt');
writer.write('some data here');
when someone submits their data, and it will work just fine if there are multiple people submitting at the same time? (So basically creating a writer every time someone submits, or just one writer which can be used repeatedly) Also do I have to close the stream afterwards?

Comment: You will want to initialize one stream beforehand, and then write to it in the request. `createWriteStream` takes in options, one of which being `autoClose`. This is true by default, so I believe you don't need to handle closing unless you want to